# How do I get 'next batch' of users using MSGraphSDK in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, microsoft-graph-api, ios10.3

I'm using [MSGraphSDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios/tree/master/MSGraphSDK) to get all users using the Microsoft Graph - but I can only get the first batch of users (default batch size is 100). I am able to get the first batch as shown below, but I can't see how the framework supports getting the next batch...

```
func getUsers(...) {
  var i = 0

  self.graphClient.users().request().getWithCompletion{
    (collection:MSCollection?, nextLink:MSGraphUsersCollectionRequest?, error:Error?) in

    if let nsError = error {
      NSLog("failed - message: \(nsError.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
      if let users = collection {

        for user: MSGraphUser in users.value as! [MSGraphUser] {
          i = i+1
          print("\(i): \(user.optDisplayName ?? "<empty>")")

          self.save(user)
        }

        // TODO: Handle next batch...
        if users.nextLink != nil {
          //self.getNextUsers(users.nextLink)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kim, what values are you seeing for users.nextLink and nextLink?

Comment: I see the link for the next batch as expected... but the framework does not fetch them automatically and I can see how to use the nextlink in the request.

Answer (score 0):

`users.nextLink` is the URL link, whereas `nextLink` is a request object that has been initialized with the next page's URL that you can invoke with `getWithCompletion` and follows the same pattern as the request shown.

Comment: Welll I'm new to Swift 3 (and iOS) - can you please provide an example... I only get an infinite loop...

Comment: In your implementation of getNextUsers - you should check to see if 'nextLink' has been set - if it is set, you have a new page available. Otherwise if it is nil, you're done. If you want to terminate early, I would add a parameter to the method keeping track of what the count of pages (or resources) has been up to a certain point so you can terminate when your limit has been reached. Does that help?

Comment: I can see how this is done using the SDK framework... You can add some options to the request() but nothing else. I tried to add the skiptoken, but it didn't work.

I have actually skipped the MSGraphSDK and now use the p2.OAuth2. Now I can control the requests (needed a beta method and the delta request on the users which the SDK didn't support). 

But I think that the issue is still relevant for others using the MSGraphSDK...